# Ordering in javascript

Tags: javascript

How easy/hard is it to order collections in javascript (alphabetical and numerically).

Say I have a collection like:

```
var map = {

    user: { id: "23434", username: "mrblah" },
    user: { id: "1010", username: "johnskeet" }

};
```

And I want to order the collection by id and username.

**Update**
correction thanks:

```
var map = [ { id: "23434", username: "mrblah" }, { id: "1010", username: "johnskeet" } ];
```

Comment: You can't have two members named user in your object. Perhaps what you want is an array? `var map = [ { id: "23434", username: "mrblah" }, { id: "1010", username: "johnskeet" } ];`

Comment: you need to convert JSON object to array then its peace of cake

Comment: Let's not confuse JavaScript object literals with JSON.

Comment: @Ates Goral: Whats difference between the two. I could only see it as  JSON object of the form http://json.org/object.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var map = { 
    users: [
        { id: "23434", username: "mrblah" },
        { id: "1010", username: "johnskeet" }
    ]
};

map.users.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a.id - b.id; 
});

map.users.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a.username.localeCompare(b.username); 
});
```

Comment: What is this `compareTo` you speak?

Comment: compareTo() is a JavaScript function I don't recognize. Is that a Java convention?

Comment: @mrblah - Negative, you pass the compare function as the argument.

Comment: I think if you just pass in `function(a, b) { return (a.username > b.username); }` into `map.users.sort()` -- my example does that.

Comment: As @ChaosPandion pointed out, my `a.username > b.username` is no good. Use `a.username.localeCompare(b.username)` in the comparison function

Answer (score -1):

You want your object to be an array:

```
var map = [
    { id: "23434", username: "mrblah" },
    { id: "1010", username: "johnskeet" },
    { id: "1220", username: "alohaguy" }
];
```

We need a utility to display the usernames in order so we can test our work:

```
var displayUsernames = function(map) {
    var out = [];
    for (var i=0;i<map.length;i++) {
        out.push((map[i].username));
    }
    alert(out.join(', '));
};
```

If we use it: `displayUsernames(map);` we get **mrblah, johnskeet, alohaguy**

Since it's an array, so we can use `.sort()`, like this: `map.sort();`, but if we do that we still get:

> **mrblah, johnskeet, alohaguy**

...from `displayUsernames(map);` because the array of objects can't be sorted the same way as if it were an array of numbers or strings.

However, if we pass the `sort()` function a comparison function...

```
var myCompareFunction = function(a, b) {
    return a.username.localeCompare(b.username);
};
```

Then pass it into `map.sort()`

```
map.sort(myCompareFunction);
```

Now, when we display it again with `displayUsernames(map);` we get **alohaguy, johnskeet, mrblah**

Hope that helps.

Comment: The compare function should not return a boolean. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @ChaosPandion - thanks, learn something every day! I changed it from `a.username > b.username` to `a.username.localeCompare(b.username);`

Comment: I cannot up-vote you, can you make some kind of modification to your answer?

Comment: @ChaosPandio - I did modify my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1678007/list ... based on your feedback.

Comment: @artlung: don't be too happy: http://michael.susens-schurter.com/blog/tag/localecompare/

Comment: @CrescentFresh hmm. Interesting, sad. I wonder how it would look if you did toLowerCase() on the strings then took the character code. Bizarre behavior. :-( Any other suggestions for sorting comparisons?